# Why sometimes I enter an integer the program prints a the first entered number into decimal number?

Tags: c++

Here is my code. As you can see the data type is float because there is a division operation. The problem I always encounter every time is that when the user wants to view the history, the first number i entered becomes a decimal number.

Here is the sample output:

History:

1.) 6*2.00263=12
2.) 3+2=5

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int add(int a, int b);
int subtract(int a, int b);
int multiply(int a, int b);
float divide(float a,float b);
int remainder(int a, int b);
void convert(int a, int b);
int main(){
    int size = 0;
    int result[size];
    float num1[size];
    float num2[size];
    char operation[size];
    char answer;
    while(true){
        cout<<"Enter two numbers: \n";
        cout<<size;
        while(!(cin>>num1[size]>>num2[size])){
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Invalid Input. PLease try again: \n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(2);
        }
    Operation:
    cout<<"Choose Operation: \n"
        <<"   +   --- Addition  \n"
        <<"   -   --- Subtraction   \n"
        <<"   *   --- Multiplication   \n"
        <<"   /   --- Division   \n"
        <<"   %   --- Remainder   \n";
    cout<<"Operation: ";
    cin>>operation[size];

    switch(operation[size]){
        case '+':
            result[size]=add(num1[size],num2[size]);
            cout<<result[size];
            break;
        case '-':
            result[size]=subtract(num1[size],num2[size]);
            break;
        case '*':
            result[size]=multiply(num1[size],num2[size]);
            break;
        case '/':
            result[size]=divide(num1[size],num2[size]);
            break;
        case '%':
            result[size]=remainder(num1[size],num2[size]);
            break;
        default:
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Please enter a valid operation.\n\n";
            goto Operation;
    }
    cout<<"Do you want to try again? (Y or N): ";
    cin>>answer;
        switch(answer){
            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
                system("cls");
                size++;
                continue;
            default:
                cout<<"Do you want to view history? ";
                cin>>answer;
                switch(answer){
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'y':
                        system("cls");
                        cout<<"History:\n\n";
                        for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
                            cout<<i+1<<".) ";
                            cout<<num1[i]<<operation[i]<<num2[i]<<"="<<result[i];
                            cout<<endl;
                        }
                        cout<<endl;
                        cout<<"Do you want to try again? (Y or N): ";
                        cin>>answer;
                            switch(answer){
                                case 'Y':
                                case 'y':
                                    system("cls");
                                    size++;
                                    continue;
                                default:
                                    cout<<"Thank you\n";
                                    return 0;
                            }
                    default:
                        cout<<"Thanky You!\n";
                        return 0;
                }
        }   
    }
}
int add(int a, int b){
    int result;
    result=a+b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<result<<endl;
    return result;
    }
int subtract(int a, int b){
    int result;
    result=a-b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<result<<endl;
    return result;
}
int multiply(int a, int b){
    int result;
    result=a*b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<result<<endl;
    return result;
    }
float divide(float a, float b){
    float result;
    result=a/b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<result<<endl;
    return result;
}
int remainder(int a, int b){
    int result;
    result=a%b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<result<<endl;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please also include the input, output and expected output. THe first number `6` has no decimal places, do you get `6` as output, but expected `6.00` ? Please clarify

Comment: You have UB in your code … `int result[size]` where `size == 0` is defining an array of size 0. Then you are accessing some random element of it later … Also, VLAs are not valid C++

Comment: And also if I change the data type into integer the results becomes wrong like if I entered 2 and 1 and the operation is addition, the result becomes 45 or something that is not accurate.

Comment: the expected ouput is 6 not 6.00

Comment: here: `cout<<"Enter two numbers: \n"; cout<<size;` didnt you notice that `size == 0` ?

Comment: "the expected ouput is 6" sorry this does not clarify but rather adds confusion. The output you posted is `6`, so what is wrong? (apart from the undefined behvior, which basically means all output is meaningless...)

Comment: oh sorry for that I meant for 2. You see I entered 6 and 2 and I chose multiplication and result is 12 and that is right. But when I viewed history, 2 became 2.00263 and that is the problem I am encountering right now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried running your code through a debugger?  You should identify the problematic code and post the minimal code required to reproduce the problem instead of showing all the code.  See [mre].

Comment: You really need a better source to learn about C++. Array with size 0 is not really valid. `array[size]` is invalid everywhere except for initialization - `size` is index outside of valid range for array defined as `int array[size]`.

Comment: as you can see, the `int result[size];` is a type of `int` so this is why you get only decimal numbers. you need to change it to the `float`

Comment: oh thats it! I have change the size into 5 and the problem is gone. Thank you all I didnt know that array with size 0 is not valid. I am new in c++ so I make mistakes hehehe

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code, relating to the arrays themselves. Firstly, in C++, when defining an array, the size must be a compile time constant, therefore:

```
int size = 0;
int results[size];
```

Is not valid C++. Presumably you are using a compiler which accepts VLAs, but this is not standard C++, and should be avoided. You should have `size` a constant.

Secondly, you are initializing arrays of size 0. From `dcl.array/1`, in reference to the size of the array, *its value shall be greater than zero*. Therefore, your array declaration is invalid. This should not even compile, however, since you're using VLAs, presumably the compiler skips this conformance check too.

Thirdly, you have the following code:

```
cin>>num1[size]>>num2[size]
```

Since `num1` and `num2` are both declared as having `size` for their size, you are going out of bounds. Arrays are only able to be access from `0` to `size-1`. This is undefined behaviour. The same issue appears several more times with different arrays.
Further, in your loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
    cout<<i+1<<".) ";
    cout<<num1[i]<<operation[i]<<num2[i]<<"="<<result[i];
    cout<<endl;
}
```

You are going up to, and including, `size`. This is again undefined behaviour.

Therefore, any output you do get from your program is entirely unknown.

Comment: thanks for the advice and I hope I will become better in programming someday